# Parameterized testing with 2 arguments in pytest running .exe file

Tags: python, cmd, pytest

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", range(17))
@pytest.mark.parametrize("y", range(11))
def test_foo(x, y)
my_test.exe, my_command 'x' 'y'
```

I want to run from "my_test.exe" the command "my_command x y" , x and y are from ranges that are above mentioned.

Comment: What doesn't work? When I look at the documentation of `pytest.mark.parametrize` this is exactly how you would mark it. 

For calling the program you would use `subprocess.check_call`

Comment: OK, so how the code will be look?

Answer (score 1):

You actually had a good start with the parametrize call, it works exactly like this. You only need to add the process-call in your method.

One example:

```
import subprocess
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", range(17))
@pytest.mark.parametrize("y", range(11))
def test_foo(x, y):
    rc = subprocess.check_call(['/bin/echo', str(x), str(y)])
    assert rc == 0

    stdout = subprocess.check_output(['/bin/echo', str(x), str(y)])
    assert stdout
```

`check_call` or `check_output` will raise an exception when the program errors, so the test fails. You also might test the output.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it doesn't work. After running the script I get nothing in the output.

Comment: just a wild guess, but did you just run your script with `python`, or did you use the proper testing command `py.test yourfile.py`?

Comment: I found this messege:  **c:\python36\lib\subprocess.py:997: FileNotFoundError**

Comment: You should replace my test -path with the actual program you want to call

Comment: My-test file and the program that I want to call are in the same direction.